# How to Apply Garbage Collection in Web Api Project?

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection

> In My Project Performance is low That's why I apply to garbage collection in entire my project. But How to apply Garbage collection in my project.
>
> for a single method to apply garbage collection use Gc.Collect().
> But in My project Multiple methods. I don't want to call every method. please give Solution.`

Comment: Why do you think doing manual garbage collection will solve your performance issues?

Comment: any other solutions

Comment: I cannot possible tell without knowing what is causing the performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use middleware for every request

Comment: I am asking How to apply Garbage collection in my project.

Comment: You can write a middleware which runs after every request so you can call gc here but if you need gc you are doing sth wrong